# Magento 2 flat catalog category not available

Tags: magento2, configuration, flat-catalog

I would like to enable Flat Catalog Category in our multistore Magento 2 (2.1.9), but I cannot find the option in **Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront**

What could be the cause of this problem?

[image]

Comment: Open the Storefront section,

Comment: This is where I was looking for it, I have updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: According to the https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html Flat Catalog is no longer recommended.

Answer (score 0):

- On the Admin Panel, `Stores > Settings > Configurations`.
- On the left panel, under `Catalog, select Catalog`.
- Open the `Storefront` section,
- Choose Yes in the Use `Flat Catalog Category` field.
- Choose Yes in the Use `Flat Catalog Product` field.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't clear enough in my question, I have updated it with a screenshot.

Comment: Magento now discourage the use of flat catalog: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the right Store View mode? The **Use Flat Catalog Category** and **Use Flat Catalog Product** options are only available in the **Global Scope** (Default Config)

[image]

Comment: I tried both (Defalt Config & webshop config), but in Default Config nothing shows p when I go to Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog. So there is no Storefront when I'm in the Global Scope.

Comment: The Storefront group is missing under the Default Config? That would explain why you're not able to see the options. No idea why it wouldn't show up though. Could be many things, like javascript errors, a config conflict or perhaps module interference. Is this a fresh install?

Comment: There is 1 javascript error, but this error also occurs in the Webshop Config when the Storefront group does show up so that doesn't seem to be the cause of this problem.